# Unix: how to read line's original content from file

Tags: unix, echo, trim, cut

I have a data file, the content is as follows:

```
department: customer service  section: A
department: marketing         section: A
department: finance           section: A
```

When I read each line, I would extract the department name using `cut` command.

Unfortunately, the program will automatically `trim` all redundant space and

thus I cut the department name incorrectly.

```
cat dept.dat | while read line
do
    echo $line
    echo $line | cut -c 12-29
done
```

e.g. the original line is

```
department: marketing         section: A
```

while the program treats this line as:

```
department: marketing section: A
```

How can I read the line without trimming all the redundant space?

Many thanks.

Comment: Becuase I need to implement some more business logic, it is required to read the file line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` doesn't modify whitespace. If you look at the output, you'll see that the whitespace is already trimmed before it's fed to `cut`.

No need for `while` and `read`, just pass the file name directly to `cut`:

```
/tmp >cat dept.dat 
department: customer service  section: A
department: marketing         section: A
department: finance           section: A    
/tmp >cut -c 12-29 dept.dat 
customer service 
marketing        
finance
```

Comment: and, if for some other reason O.P. needs to use loop, the quote references like `"$line"`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread his post. `echo "$line"` is the *real* solution.

Comment: Thanks for all who have provided suggestion. It solves my problems now.